# How to show multiple selected dates in flutter calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm creating an app where I want to show a list of dates by a symbol or by a different color on a calendar.
The final output I want to achieve looks like this.
[Here is the reference image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csez5.jpg)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is this package useful [calendarro](https://pub.dev/packages/calendarro)?

Comment: @Hemal This package doesn;t support null safety

Comment: @SandeepSharma I tried flutter table_calendar, there is no such option to focus on multiple dates. So, I tried event loader but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. I used [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package for this project. I used eventsloader method in the TableCalendar Object.

1. Firstly I create a list of DateTime and an empty Dictionary of key
   DateTime and List values.
2. In the init function I used foreach loop in the list and added each
   element of list as a key to dictionary with value as [""].
3. I create a getEvents(Datetime day) method that will be called by
   eventsloader and it will pass list of DateTime to the function
   getEvents.
4. In the getEvents body I returned the value of dictionary after
   passing the day as key if it is null return empty list.
5. If you want to customize the look of the calendar like change the
   default blue color of event to something else. Use calenderbuilder  method of TableCalendar. pass CalendarBuilder() as an argument to calendarbuilder and inside CalendarBuilder() use markerBuilder.

Comment: Can you please provide your source code. I will be very thankful to you.